# Generating Android build with Gitlab CI

Tags: android, gitlab-ci

I just installed Gitlab as repository for my projects and I want to take advantages of their Gitlab CI system. I want to automatically generate a distribution and debug Apk after each commit. I googled but I didn't find anything as a tutorial or similar cases. If someone could guide me in some way, it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested about it too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've just written a blog post on [how to setup Android builds in Gitlab CI using shared runners](http://www.greysonparrelli.com/post/setting-up-android-builds-in-gitlab-ci-using-shared-runners/).

The quickest way would be to have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` with the following contents:

```yaml
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_TARGET_SDK: "24"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "24.0.0"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "24.4.1"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.tgz https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.tgz
  - tar --extract --gzip --file=android-sdk.tgz
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_TARGET_SDK}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

build:
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
```

This starts off using the Java 8 Docker image, then proceeds to download and install the necessary bits of the Android SDK before your build runs. My post also goes into detail as to how you can build this into a Docker image and host it on Gitlab itself.

Hopefully that helps!

**UPDATE - 4/10/2017**

I wrote the canonical blog post for setting up Android builds in Gitlab CI back in November '16 for the official Gitlab blog. Includes details on how to run tests and such as well. Linking here.

https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/

Answer (score 3):

You can add a build step to your GitLab CI project as below.

```
gradle assemble
```

[image]

This will generate debug and release APK's of the commit pushed at:

```
/build/outputs/apk/
```

You could then write a script to archive the generated APK's however you require.